# Strange solution for the integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Reading some examples in my theory book, I met strange solution and I can't figure out how did they got it. Here it is $$\int \frac{v \, dv}{\sqrt{v^4 +g^2r^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\ln{ \frac{v^2+\sqrt{v^4+g^2r^2}}{gr}}+C,$$ where $g,r$ are constants. I can't understand why they have $gr$ in the denominator. Is it a misprint, or it has some meaning which I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This example looks like it comes from physics - the $gr$ in the denominator of the log is there to make the argument of the log a dimensionless number. note that it can be absorbed into the definition of $C$ ( provided that $gr$ is positive )

Comment: Yes it is from physics. Thx for clarifying the need for this trick.

Comment: Nice point.  Physicists' points of view can shed light in places that often remain dark otherwise. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So, merely saying that $g,r$ are constants will not allow us to solve the problem ("why is $gr$ in the denominator?").  But providing the units for everything there may allow us to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{v \, dv}{\sqrt{v^4 +g^2r^2}} = \int \frac{\frac 1 2\,du}{\sqrt{u^2+g^2 r^2}} = \frac 1 2 \int \frac{du/gr}{\sqrt{\left(\frac u{gr}\right)^2 + 1}} = \underbrace{\frac 1 2 \int \frac{\sec^2\theta\,d\theta}{\sqrt{\tan^2\theta + 1}}}_{\text{No $gr$ appears here.}} \\[12pt]
= {} & \overbrace{\frac 1 2 \int \sec\theta\,d\theta}^{\text{No $gr$ appears here.}} = \frac 1 2 \ln(\tan\theta+\sec\theta) + \text{constant} \\[12pt] 
= {} &  \frac 1 2 \ln((u/gr) + \sqrt{(u/gr)^2 + 1}) + \text{constant} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \ln \frac{u + \sqrt{u^2+ g^2r^2}}{gr} + \text{constant} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \ln(u + \sqrt{u^2 + g^2r^2})\, \underbrace{{}-\ln(gr) + \text{constant}}_{\text{This is a constant.}}
\end{align}

You don't *need* $gr$ in the answer; it is equally correct to write it without that, however: it's correct either way, since the answer with $gr$ and that without it **differ from each other by a constant,** which is $\ln(1/gr)$.

But the argument above shows how it can get there.

Remember that "constant" in this case means not changing as the variable $v$ changes.

Answer (score 4):

Since $g$ and $r$ constants, we can write 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\ln{ \frac{v^2+\sqrt{v^4+g^2r^2}}{gr}}+C
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(v^2+\sqrt{v^4+g^2r^2} \ \right)}- \frac{1}{2}\ln(gr)+C \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(v^2+\sqrt{v^4+g^2r^2} \ \right)}+D.
\end{align}
Anyhow, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_integrals

Substitute $u=v^2$, that integral can be written as $\sinh^{-1}$